# I get Compiler Error on C# Can you help me?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am getting an error can you help me

Visual Studio says there is a problem with the h in the print part:

> Error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'h' (CS0165)

```
static void Main()
{
    int[ , ] m = new int [8,8];
    int i ;
    int h ;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for( i = 0 ; i< 8 ; i++)
    {
        for( h = 0 ; h< 8 ; h++)
        {
            m[i,h] = rnd.Next(10);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(m[i,h]);
      
}
```

Comment: And what is the exact error message?  The error is trying to tell you what the problem is, it's best to read and examine it.

Comment: I've been working on c# for a month, I'm not good yet on c#, I looked but I don't understand

Comment: Is Visual Studio really telling you "There is a problem with the h in the print part"?  Or is there a specific error message?

Comment: Error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'h' (CS0165)

Comment: The compiler doesn't 'know' that the inner loop is supposed to assign a value to h so it doesn't assume it. Why (on earth) don't you initialize your variables??? Always the recommended practice. (Unless you want to test the compiler;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your variables have no assigned values:

```
int i ;
int h ;
```

Now, the compiler knows that `i` *will* be assigned a value here:

```
for( i = 0 ; i< 8 ; i++)
```

Without looking too deep under the hood, basically the `i = 0` part is guaranteed to happen whether the loop body executes or not.  Then *we* know that `h` will also be assigned a value here:

```
for( h = 0 ; h< 8 ; h++)
```

Because *we* know that the outer loop will execute at least once, because we know 0 is less than 8.  But the compiler isn't as aware of this.  The compiler follows a simpler set of rules for the guarantees that it makes.  And those rules do not include executing the program's logic to see if something will or won't happen.

So the bottom line is that, while the compiler *can* guarantee that `i` will be assigned a value, it *can not* guarantee that `h` will.  Hence the error.

The simple solution is just to assign values to your variables:

```
int i = 0;
int h = 0;
```

Comment: actually I tried this but this time i get another error too... System.IndexOutOfRangeException has been thrown

Comment: @umut: Google is your friend: [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20940979/328193)  Now is also a great time for you to start using a debugger to observe the exact runtime values of your variables.  You will probably find that on the last line of your program, `i` and `h` have the value `8`, which is invalid for that array.